# KeyError in InvoiceYearMonth. Was working well in the code written above in Jupyter Notebooks in Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

```
# Revenue = Active Customer Count * Order Count * Average Revenue per Order

#converting the type of Invoice Date Field from string to datetime.
tx_data['InvoiceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(tx_data['InvoiceDate'])

#creating YearMonth field for the ease of reporting and visualization
tx_data['InvoiceYearMonth'] = tx_data['InvoiceDate'].map(lambda date: 100*date.year + date.month)

#calculate Revenue for each row and create a new dataframe with YearMonth - Revenue columns
tx_data['Revenue'] = tx_data['UnitPrice'] * tx_data['Quantity']
tx_revenue = tx_data.groupby(['InvoiceYearMonth'])['Revenue'].sum().reset_index()
tx_revenue
```

```
    #creating a new dataframe with UK customers only
    tx_uk = tx_data.query("Country=='United Kingdom'").reset_index(drop=True)

    #creating monthly active customers dataframe by counting unique Customer IDs
    tx_monthly_active = tx_uk.groupby('InvoiceYearMonth')['CustomerID'].nunique().reset_index()

    #print the dataframe
    tx_monthly_active

    #plotting the output
     plot_data = [
         go.Bar(
             x=tx_monthly_active.query['InvoiceYearMonth'],
             y=tx_monthly_active.query['CustomerID'],
         )
     ]

     plot_layout = go.Layout(
     xaxis={"type": "category"},
     title='Monthly Active Customers'
         )

     fig = go.Figure(data=plot_data, layout=plot_layout)
     pyoff.iplot(fig)
```

It was working in the code I had written earlier. But it is showing an error here. I would really appreciate it if a solution were to be given. I am using Jupyter Notebook in Pycharm. I cannot really figure not what the issue is. I am still new to programming so I am finding it a bit difficult to navigate through this issue.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-26-82f7e61120b9> in <module>
      3 
      4 #creating monthly active customers dataframe by counting unique Customer IDs
----> 5 tx_monthly_active = tx_uk.groupby('InvoiceYearMonth')['CustomerID'].nunique().reset_index()
      6 
      7 #print the dataframe

c:\users\aayus\pycharmprojects\helloworld\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed)
   5799         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   5800 
-> 5801         return groupby_generic.DataFrameGroupBy(
   5802             obj=self,
   5803             keys=by,

c:\users\aayus\pycharmprojects\helloworld\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, mutated)
    400             from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import get_grouper
    401 
--> 402             grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
    403                 obj,
    404                 keys,

c:\users\aayus\pycharmprojects\helloworld\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate)
    596                 in_axis, name, level, gpr = False, None, gpr, None
    597             else:
--> 598                 raise KeyError(gpr)
    599         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
    600             # Add key to exclusions

KeyError: 'InvoiceYearMonth'
```

Comment: The issue is probably earlier in the code, try printing tx_data to see if it contains what you expect. Perhaps you've changed something and now it's not loading the data you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. It was a basic syntax error.
Instead of typing this

```
tx_monthly_active = tx_uk.groupby('InvoiceYearMonth')['CustomerID'].nunique().reset_index()
```

we have to type

```
tx_monthly_active = x_uk.groupby(['InvoiceYearMonth'])'CustomerID'].nunique().reset_index()
```